# Question is actually two questions. How to act?

Tags: support

The [What are some cards that are vulnerable to RFID theft?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62484/what-are-some-cards-that-are-vulnerable-to-rfid-theft) has been edited by the OP and is now 2 different questions.

The answers are split likewise.
Answerer Iserni took the precaution of quoting the one question he is anwering, but most people don't do that.

Should I just flag/other/'Needs moderator attention' with a request to split the question into two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance, I saw this meta question but the usual process is to flag as other and list the reason.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to vote to close it as "too broad" (or if you don't have reputation to vote to close, flag it for moderator attention).

Another approach is to edit the question to focus on one question, and post a separate new question for the other part.  However, this might not be ideal if there are also multiple answers that address both parts -- i.e., if it makes existing answers obsolete or hard to understand.

You can also post a comment to let the author know about how to use the site most effectively, for their future knowledge.